# Problema sesion , No se pudo restablecer la vista Prime Faces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tengo una Aplicación JSF pero después de un tiempo cierro la sesión pero me da el siguiente error y no redirecciona al login.

```
public String cerrarSession() {
    SessionUtils.getSession().invalidate();
    return "/login";
}
```

**Clase SessionUtils**

```
public class SessionUtils {

public static HttpSession getSession() {
    return (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext().getSession(false);
}

public static HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
    return (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext().getRequest();
}

public static String getUserName() {
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    return session.getAttribute("username").toString();
}

public static String getUserId() {
    HttpSession session = getSession();
    if (session != null) {
        return (String) session.getAttribute("userid");
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

> Grave: javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:...
>
> No se pudo restablecer la vista ....

Comment: Es posible que estés sobre la misma vista que tiene alcance `@ViewScoped` o `@SessionScoped` y quiera obtener la vista desde la sesión, pero como la sesión ha sido invalidada la vista ya no se puede obtener (porque no existe). Intenta realizar un redirect a tu página de login en lugar de un forward.

Answer (score 1):

Tal parece que tu vista al invalidar la sesión ya no está disponible. Intenta con **redirect.**

```
 public static final String LOGOUT_PAGE_REDIRECT = "/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
```

En método logout:

```
 public String cerrarSession() {

        // Se invalida la sesion
        LOGGER.debug("invalidando sesion....");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .invalidateSession();

        LOGGER.info("Sesion invalidada! ");
        return LOGOUT_PAGE_REDIRECT;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema debe estar del lado del browser, puedes intentar implementando el siguiente componente de primefaces

```
<p:poll interval="#{session.maxInactiveInterval}" listener="#{tuBean.cerrarSesion()}" />
```

El session.maxInactiveInterval es el tiempo máximo de tu session medido en segundos